# Target SDK stuck on 22

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

For a couple of days I have been struggling to get the apk built with `targetSdkVersion` being 26+ in order to be able to upload it to google.

React-native version used is "^0.57.0-rc.4".

I am running the build not via Android Studio but in a form of a shell script.

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleRelease
# zipalign & sign
~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.1/aapt list -a 200hp.apk | grep SdkVersion
```

In `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In `android/build.gradle`:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27
                /* targetSdkVersion 27 */
                buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
            }
        }
    }
}

ext {
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "10.2.4"
    targetSdkVersion         = "27.0.1"
}
```

What I am getting is an error from Google saying "Your app currently targets API level 22" and the respective response from aapt: `A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x16`

Worth saying I have proper build-tools installed.

```
ls $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/
23.0.1  25.0.0  25.0.2  25.0.3  26.0.1  26.0.2  27.0.0  27.0.1  27.0.3
```

Adding `targetSdkVersion 27` into the `android/app/build.gradle` into `android`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    targetSdkVersion 27
```

Results in

> Could not find method targetSdkVersion() for arguments [27] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Uncommenting `targetSdkVersion` in `afterEvaluate` results in

> problem occurred configuring project ':RNGL'.
>   Could not find method targetSdkVersion() for arguments [27] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

I am not so much of an Android developer or someone having experience with gradle, so apologies if it's a noob question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlinking all 3rd-partly libraries proved this was a project configuration issue. I followed Martin's advice, but this did not change the resulting targetSdk version (or at least was not sufficient).

What worked for me is changing gradle distribution url from:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip
```

and running the build process in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

that `targetSdkVersion = "27.0.1"` (string) should be `27` (integer) instead.

... while it obviously hints for `com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension`

therefore I'd suspect one library module, which may still reference this wrongful value.

Comment: Well, it says "> Could not find method targetSdkVersion() for arguments [27] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

Comment: I read that adding targetSdk overrides dependency settings, should that be sufficient?

Comment: @AlexanderMikhalchenko in general it is more common to refer from within a module to `rootProject.ext` - instead of applying the `android` configuration into the other direction. that's more flexible, because sub-projects still can have a different configuration, which the example above does not permit. ever tried building the sub-projects, one by one? this should help to narrow it down.

Comment: I replaced all occurrences of `targetSdkVersion 22` from all submodules. Also, `ext.targetSdkVersion` was set to `27`, but the response remains `Could not find method targetSdkVersion() for arguments [27] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: @AlexanderMikhalchenko try commenting out the whole `afterEvaluate` - also it should be possible with the `cd`, simply `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` - or `./gradlew android:clean android:assembleDebug` to build only the module. it's in general all more complex than it would have to be.

Comment: Thanks, now at least I am getting a different error, `/Users/strrife/Projects/hp200/node_modules/gl-react-native/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.` which appears to be googlable :)

Comment: @AlexanderMikhalchenko guess the reason merely was changing into the sub-directory (which most likely not applied the values, as expected). while that resource should be contained in later version of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`... `27.1.1` is the latest stable version.